# Packaging multiple libs containing the same file - Ant

Tags: java, ant

In my Java project I use Ant to build. Considering I have quite a few dependencies I'd like to ship the application with all libraries packaged into a single jar (and the main app in the other one).

I currently use the following code to do that:

```
<target name="package-to-2-jars" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="main"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <property name="storelibs.jar" value="${store.dir}/sdk.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging main classes and libraries into two separate JARs at ${store.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final_lib.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" excludes="*fonts*.jar"/>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
                    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <zip destfile="${storelibs.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final_lib.jar"
                    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final_lib.jar"/>
</target>
```

At first all looked nice. However, in some cases something didn't work as expected. After a while I've realized that my sdk.jar contains multiple files with the same name.

**The thing is: some of my dependency libraries (multiple jars of the same sdk) come with a properties file. Each of them contains different data but all of them share the same name. Is it possible to package those libraries into a single jar in such a way that the application will be able to access those different files with the same name?**

All I've found so far is a *duplicate* attribute of zip/jar task but that won't work for me. I need to preserve data from all the files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a while I've managed to solve this issue myself. Here is my solution. I doubt it is the best but it works for me so it's good enough.

```
<target name="package-to-2-jars" depends="jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="main"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>
    <property name="storelibs.jar" value="${store.dir}/sdk.jar"/>
    <echo message="Packaging main classes and libraries into two separate JARs at ${store.jar}"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <for param="file">
        <path>
            <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <concat destfile="${store.dir}/file.txt" append="yes" fixlastline="true">
                <zipentry zipfile="@{file}" name="file.txt"/>
            </concat>
        </sequential>
    </for>       

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final_lib.jar" filesetmanifest="skip" duplicate="preserve">
        <zipfileset file="${store.dir}/file.txt"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" excludes="*fonts*.jar"/>
    </jar>
    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
                    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <zip destfile="${storelibs.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final_lib.jar"
                    excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final_lib.jar"/>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/file.txt"/>
</target>
```